# Adding provisioning profiles on iOS with XCode5 in delphi XE5

Tags: xcode, delphi, ios7, delphi-xe5

I have an iOS 7 device that I want to ad-hoc deploy my app using XCode5. How can I put the provisioning profile on the device? - note that I am using delphi XE5 to write the app, not xcode.

The way I have used for other devices and that is listed in the Embarcadero documentation doesn't seem to be applicable for XCode5. In the help I have looked up for XCode5, it seems to suggest that you use the XCode project manager to add the provisioning profiles, and they get bundled up with the project.

However XE5 doesn't use the project manager as far as I am aware, and I am at a loss as to how to get the provisioning profile on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know one thing , in your Provisioning profile your device is added or not, if your Device is added and you want to create a ad-hoc build and want to install this app in your ios Device then you have to create the ipa file , with IPA , you does not need to add in your Device because through ipa file  the provisioning profile automatically add in your Device

How to create a IPA

1) Set the Provisioning Profile in your Xcode --- go to Build Phase -- code signin

if you sucessfully set your Provisioning Profile in your xcode then

2)  go to Product --Archive  ...with this you have to create the ipa

Sync the IPA in your itunes and install the app in your Device

SECOND WAY TO INSTALL THE IOS APP IN IPHONE,IPAD,IPOD,

however there is also a Simple way to install the IPA

1) if you create the IPA successfully  then please open the    www.diawi.com

2) Upload the ipa in  diawi.com  after your IPA is uploading successfully a  send button will be appear
 so you have to click the send button a Link will be appear ,

3) Open that link in your iphone,ipad, safari browser , with this you have to install your App without Syncing in itunes

Comment: if you want to create a Proviosining Profile then please use this link to create a Fresh Provisioning Profile                                               http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12/provisioning-5-create-profile

Comment: I have a provisioning profile, but it is not on the iOS7 device. I am not using XCode to write the project. I am using delphi XE5, (and which creates the IPA file)

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear that I am using delphi XE5 to write my iOS application.

Comment: You probably still need to use XCode to access the device organizer and set up the profiles, even with Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps here regarding the provisioning profile:

http://goo.gl/1Knh2t